# How to calculate the geometric mean and ignore 0s in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe consisting of 13 columns of daily stock returns for certain stocks.  I want to calculate the geometric mean of each column but some have zeros in the column as those businesses materialized on the stock market at different times.

I know numpy's arithmetic mean will ignore NaNs.  Is there some way to calculate the geometric mean and ignore zeros at the same time?

sample df:

```
import pandas as pd
dictA = {'AAPL': [.02, -.001, .05, .43], 'ABC':[.03, -.02, -.05, 0], 'DEF': [.045, 0, -.10, .63]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dictA)
```

The geometric mean for `AAPL` would be `.02 * -.001 * .05 * .43**(1/N)` where N is the number of observations.

Is there some sort of slick code that can calculate the geometric mean while ignoring zeros?

Answer (score 2):

One way is using [`np.multiply.reduce`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) and `np.where` to replace those `0` to `1` so they do not modify the result, and divide by the amount of non-zero values per column:

```
a = df.values
m = (a!=0)
np.multiply.reduce(np.where(m, a, 1), axis=0)**(1/m.sum(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Geometric means isn't good for lists with negative values in them (some of these results return imaginary numbers), but that being said, here's one answer to your question:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def geometric_mean(values):
    return float(np.prod([x for x in values])) ** (1 / len([x for x in values]))

dictA = {'AAPL': [.02, -.001, .05, .43], 'ABC': [.03, -.02, -.05, 0], 'DEF': [.045, 0, -.10, .63]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dictA)

cols = ['AAPL', 'ABC', 'DEF']
for col in cols:
    # exclude 0s from being passed to the function
    print(geometric_mean(df.loc[df[col] != 0, col]))
```

EDIT: I originally had `return np.prod([x for x in values]) ** (1 / len([x for x in values]))`. I changed this to `return float(np.prod([x for x in values])) ** (1 / len([x for x in values]))` so the function will now return imaginary numbers if the product of the list is negative.

Comment: Thanks Caleb.  There are 0s somwhere in all the columns and it returns NaN for those.  I need it to ignore the zeros not the entire column if there is a zero.

Comment: @Jordan The reason `nan`s are being returned is not because of the 0s, but because of the negative values. This is how geometric mean works: 
`.02 * -.001 * .05 * .43 = -4.3000000000000007e-07`
`-4.3000000000000007e-07 ** (1/ 4) = nan`
This has nothing to do with 0s in the formula, and everything to do with the fact that initial product of all the values is a negative number.

Comment: @Jordan I converted the `np.product` into a `float`, so if you use the function with an array that has a negative product, it will return an imaginary value, as it should. Just my two cents though, I think that geometric mean is the incorrect way to go about this if you have negative values in your list.

Comment: @Jordan "Like zero, it is impossible to calculate Geometric Mean with negative numbers. However, there are several work-arounds for this problem, all of which require that the negative values be converted or transformed to a meaningful positive equivalent value. Most often, this problem arises when it is desired to calculate the geometric mean of a percent change in a population or a financial return, which includes negative numbers."
source: https://buzzardsbay.org/special-topics/calculating-geometric-mean/

Comment: Ha!  I'm doing this for financial returns.  I"ll check out the article.  Thanks for helping  me out.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function that takes all elements in a column and returns one element. Apply it to every column (in the axis=0 direction).

```
from functools import reduce

def g_mean(n):
    """Find the geometric mean for iterable n."""

    # Make a list with every element in n that != 0.
    l = [e for e in n if e !=0]

    tot = reduce(lambda a,b: a*b, l) # Multiply all elements in l.
    return tot**(1/(len(l)))

df.apply(g_mean) # Apply g_mean(column) to every column.
```

Comment: Thanks David.  Getting this:  `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: I made mistakes. It should work now. I wrote def g_mean(*n)

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Everything is explained now.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out for negative numbers.  If I have a data frame of stock returns with negative numbers, I do the following:

```
from scipy.stats import gmean
gmean(1+df, axis = 0) - 1
```

Comment: It is important to note that this solution would not ignore zeros which may or may not be what you are looking for.  For example, if there were stocks with zero returns just because of when they materialized on the market, you may not want those stocks pulling down your average.